# Vertically align middle the content of a col-* bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, vertical-alignment

This is html -

```
<div class="col-lg-12 vertical-align">
      Course 1 
      <span class="pull-right btn btn-success">read more</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
 .vertical-align 
 {
    /*line-height: 45px;*/
    display: block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width:100%;
 }
```

Without line-height specified, it looks like-
[image]

if line-height: 45px, it looks like
[image]

How can I align vertically both the element?

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize `btn` class.

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-lg-12 vertical-align">
      <span class="btn btn-nope">Course 1</span>
      <span class="pull-right btn btn-success">read more</span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.btn-nope {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    cursor: default;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding a [`p.form-control-static`](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-controls-static) to the *Course 1* text vertically aligns it to form elements such as a button. I would first try to see if you can make it work with the following example (two columns, `.text-right` instead of floating the button using `.pull-right`) before trying anything else.

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <p class="form-control-static">Course 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 text-right">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">read more</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**P.S.** http://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/ is a great resource for centering content using CSS. Having a floating element however might prove to be an issue.